# I need help with classes - class for displaying filenames, file size, path, and anything else

Tags: python, file, class

Alright I have a gigantic list of files I would like to copy from one place to another. I would like to make a class to store all of this data. I want to be able to call two class instances, one with files in one drive, the other with the files in the other drive. I then get the size, whether or not the other drive has a similar file, etc, and then copy everything. I don't know whether or not I need the fileName class, or if I can put that all in fileNames. Any pointers or tips? Do I have the general idea, or am I way off?

This is all I have so far as I'm stuck (classes have been a hard conceptual leap for me)

```
class fileNames:
    def __init__(self):
        fileSizeList = []
        filePathList = []
        fileList = []
        fileNameList.apped(fileName.name)
        fileSizeList.append(fileName.size)
        filePathList.append(fileName.path)

    def makeSizeList(fileList):
        for name in fileList:
            fileSizeList.append(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(name.path, name))))


class fileName:
    def __init__(self, name, path, size):
        self.name = name
        self.path = path
        self.size = size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the other way around: you want a class to represent a single file's data, and **not** a class to represent a bunch of them. For that, you just make an ordinary list, and put file-data instances in the list. You can use ordinary functions to create these lists.

`fileName` is a poor choice of name, because the class represents more than the file's name. Calling it `file` is also a bad idea because that is the name of a built-in thing that you use to actually read from files. :)

Having separate 'name' and 'path' fields is redundant: the name is a part of the path. Unless you want to split it up explicitly - to do this, use `os.path.split`.

Instead of making a full-blown class for the file data, you could try using a `namedtuple` instead - this saves you from writing all the class boiler-plate, and just lets you get to the business of referring to the `.path` and `.size` of a file.

Something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
# We define our data type like this:
fileData = namedtuple('fileData', ('name', 'path', 'size'))

# Now we can create an instance of it:

def pathToData(pathAndName):
    path, name = os.path.split(pathAndName)
    size = os.path.getsize(pathAndName)
    return fileData(name, path, size)

# Or a whole bunch at once, using a list comprehension:
def pathsToData(filePaths):
    return [pathToData(p) for p in filePaths]
    # There is no need to do all the 'append' logic yourself.
```

To handle a directory tree with subfolders and stuff, you should look up the `os.walk` function.